# Accessing FD (3) for Asterisk EAGI

Tags: go, asterisk

I have the following Golang code that seems to be blocking indefinitely

```
eagi := os.NewFile(uintptr(3), "/dev/stdeagi")
data := bufio.NewReaderSize(eagi, 64*1024)
...
data.WriteTo(conn) // Blocks indefinitely!
```

It doesn't even seem to throw an error - my guess is, I'm accessing the FD incorrectly. My purpose is to access the Process' FD 3 for [Asterisk EAGI](https://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+EAGI). I have also tried reading the alternative path `fmt.Sprintf("/proc/%d/fd/3", os.Getpid())`, but this seems to behave the same way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you certain that you have a file descriptor 3? Have you tried just opening the file?

Comment: @JimB When I do an `ls /proc/<PID>/fd` inside my Docker container, I see a `3`. When I try to `cat` it, I get `Permission Denied`

Comment: @Flimzy I've used https://golang.org/pkg/os/#pkg-variables as inspiration, and that's what Go seems to use?

Comment: @Angad: from what I can see, your code is _supposed_ to block indefinitely. That won't return until fd 3 is closed. Is it sending anything over the connection? Have you tried reading and writing in separate steps to see if you're making progress?

Comment: @JimB Hmm - will give the standard Read/Write approach a shot, but if I remember correctly, WriteTo simply drains the buffer, ie it's a combination of a Read/Write call internally. So it should keep writing buffers multiple times  until it hits an io.EOF

Comment: @Angad: no, WriteTo to will block until it reaches EOF. It wouldn't be very usefull if it just called Read once and returned, which would be exactly the same as calling Read once yourself.

Comment: @JimB that would explain it! Let me confirm this solves the issue, and we can create your answer and accept :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141505/discussion-between-angad-and-jimb).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right way to do this is `syscall.Read(fd int, buf []byte) (n int, err error)` ([doc](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Read)). As regards my issue, from inside the Asterisk console, a call to `sip show channelstats` showed that I wasn't receiving RTP packets altogether, and that the Read was blocking because there really was nothing to read. My networking setup needed work.